# "the system cannot find the file specified" facing this error on deploying a web service to IIS8

Tags: web-config, filenotfoundexception, iis-8

We have recently deployed a web application and a corresponding web service to the IIS8 environment.

The web service builds perfectly fine on local and accesses the .pfx file from the shared path. The path mentioned in the web.config is something like this - \\Servername\Applications\ApplicationName\key.pfx.

However, on accessing the Web service after deploying it to the IIS8 server, it is throwing an exception as 'The System cannot find the file specified' while it is trying to read the .pfx file.

I searched several answers posted in this site as well as other forums but didn't get any proper resolution.

Would be really glad if someone can help me on this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your path mentioned in the web.config are valid and the name of controller is the same in your application..

Look at :
firewall settings from the web server to the database server

connection string errors..